# Getting previous value of mdSlider (Angular Material2)

Tags: angular, angular-material2

In Angular-Material 2

I would like to limit the md-slider option to a certain value, **within** the min and max values for the slider. For example:

```
<md-slider [min]="1" [max]="100></md-slider>
```

I would like to prevent the user from moving the slider to anything above 50 on the slider but still, show the right 50% of the slider. Since there is no current way to do this visually, I wanted to revert the slide from anything above 50 to wherever the user started to move it.

Is there any natural way to do this? The @Output() change event fired after the user moves the slider only provides the final value, not the previous value.

Thank you

Comment: Cache `previousValue` in your component class whenever a change occurs. Then restore that if the change is unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if understood well the effect you are looking, but here is the solution:

**HTML:**

```
<md-slider min="0" #mySlide max="100"  (change)="mySlide.value=mySlide.value>50 ? 50 : mySlide.value"></md-slider>
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/kHJITLLiEb4HXw0BWdw9?p=preview)

Comment: It's better to use Math.max but you will need to do it in the class